# 2 databases on the one H2 instance

Tags: spring, hibernate, h2

I have JPA Repository with @Query that joins tables from other DBs, that located on the same server.

```
SELECT id,co.name from Agenc a inner join[other_db_mame].[schema_name].[table_name] co .....
```

I want to write integration tests to cover the flow with this query.
In intégration tests I use H2 DB
And my question is, how to correctly configure H2 DB to have 2 DBs and make this query work?
Maybe there is a way, to create another db via scripts, or smth like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

H2 supports direct access only to one database at once, but you can create linked tables to tables from other databases.

To create a linked table, you can use a `CREATE LINKED TABLE` command:
https://h2database.com/html/commands.html#create_linked_table

```
CREATE LINKED TABLE targetTableName('', 'jdbcURL', 'username', 'password', 'sourceTableName');
```

You can also link the whole schema with `LINK_SCHEMA` function:
https://h2database.com/html/functions.html#link_schema

```
CALL LINK_SCHEMA('targetSchemaName', '', 'jdbcURL', 'username', 'password', 'sourceSchemaName');
```

Note that format of fully-qualified table name in H2 (and in the SQL Standard) is `catalogName.schemaName.tableName`. H2 supports only one catalog (and its name is the same as a name of database) and you can't define additional catalogs. Non-standard -syntax with `[identifier]` is not accepted by H2 unless you use a `MSSQLServer` compatibility mode. In this mode you can use that syntax, but you can't have different names of catalogs anyway, so if they are fixed in your application, you have a problem.

Actually H2 can ignore the specified name of catalog if `IGNORE_CATALOGS` setting is set to `TRUE`:
https://h2database.com/html/commands.html#set_ignore_catalogs

```
SET IGNORE_CATALOGS TRUE;
```

But if combinations of schema and table name aren't unique in your original configuration, there is nothing to do with H2. You can't create different tables with the same schema and table name in H2 in any way.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So to create linked table I need to run second h2 instance and create external table here?

Comment: If you use two H2 databases, you can create in one of them links to needed tables from another database, but they must have different schema or table names. If you don't have them yet, you can try to store all the data in one database, in that case you don't need linked tables. `IGNORE_CATALOGS` may help to allow usage of any identifiers as names of the catalog. But, again, you need to have unique schema/table name combinations for each your table.

Comment: Thank you very much, I' ll try to use IGNORE_CATALOGS

Comment: Thank you for the `SET IGNORE_CATALOGS TRUE;` it worked for me.